# When is hashing not a good approach in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I wanted to know when is hashing not a good approach to follow. I know that the hash function might be bad and all, but is there any other reason based upon which we can say that this question or problem would be bad to solve through hashing.

Comment: Apart from the obvious answer of a great hash-less solution being obvious?

Comment: @sammyiitgkp - Do you mean you are wondering if there are situations that would seem to call for a hash but where it wouldn't work for some non-obvious reason?  Or are you really wondering if hashes are the ideal data structure for every algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Hashes can collide (they're not guaranteed to be unique for every input). Thus, if you have a situation where a hash collision would be unacceptable, then you shouldn't use hashes.

Hashes are also generally unordered relative to the original input. That is, the hash of "1" is not guaranteed to be greater than the hash of "2", et cetera. So if you're trying to do operations on ordered data and preserve the order, hashing probably isn't useful.

Finally (and hopefully obviously), hashes are lossy - you can't recover the original hashed text from just the hash. Thus, they shouldn't completely replace the original data unless you intentionally way to go one way (e.g. passwords).

Comment: Collisions can be resolve, can't they? Any specific scenarios in mind where this is not feasible?

Comment: @delnan It depends on what the hashes are being used for. Hence "a situation where a hash collision is unacceptable."

Comment: I read that, but I have a hard time imagining a situation where collisions cannot be resolved where hashes would be a good fit otherwise. I hoped you had a specific example.

Comment: i know abouth the non uniform hashing , chaining and things. But is there any cap like the value of n or range using which we can tell

Answer (score 0):

Bare hashes can cause security issues. For example, if you MD5 a common password the hashes are all similar and you have a major security flaw.

Comment: There are plenty of hash functions which are cryptographically secure, and several approaches to fixing rainbow table attacks. This is not a problem with hash functions, it's a problem with a their use -- you can spoil *any* application of *anything* that way.

Comment: Too bad the issue pops up in the news every so often... I was also under the impression that a standard hash function will map to a common hash for a given input. Statistically speaking, that can make it pretty easy to deduce the original password by looking at frequencies.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. It's true that these things, like most other security-related things, are easy to screw up (often in very subtle ways). But this is not related to this question, as it's not caused by using hashes per se, only by using weak/broken/non-secure hashes, applying them in a wrong way, or neglecting other security measures.